# Distinct Dictionary Using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the dictionary of distinct values using LINQ.
I have tried using this:

```
var roleRefList = 
    xDocument.Root.Descendants()
             .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleRef") && 
                         !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")))) && 
                         !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")))))
             .Select(l => new {
                  roleUri = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")).Value,
                  href = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")).Value
              })
             .Distinct()
             .ToDictionary(a => a.roleUri);
```

The problem here is that when there are duplicate entries in the `roleUri` then an error occurs.
I  am parsing the XML document and making a dictionary of xElement attributes `roleUri` and `roleref` if they are present in the xElement.

The other workaround is using a for loop:

```
Dictionary<string, string> roleRefList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (XElement element in xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleRef")))
            {
                string roelUri = Convert.ToString(element.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")));
                string href = Convert.ToString(element.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")));
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(roelUri) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(href) && !roleRefList.ContainsKey(roelUri))
                {
                    roleRefList.Add(roelUri, href);
                }
            }
```

but I want to implement this using LINQ.

Comment: Why do you want to implement this using Linq if you have working code?

Comment: What is the reason of using nodes local names? Your xml has different namespaces declared? Can you show example of xml you are parsing?

Comment: So based on your loop: if `roleUri` exists more than once, you want just the first instance of it (and its `roleRef`) in the Dictionary? Have I got this right?

Comment: @Marteen since linq is faster so needed that.

Comment: @ lazyberezovsky If i tried using Namespaces but it was giving me error.So i used name.Localname

Comment: Then @Marcin's "Group then First" approach is exactly how I'd do it.

Answer (score 8):

You could write your own `Distinct` method that would take `Func<T,TKey>` as an argument. You can find example of that here: [Distinct list of objects based on an arbitrary key in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742682/distinct-list-of-objects-based-on-an-arbitrary-key-in-linq)

With that method you should be able to write:

```
var roleRefList = xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleRef") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")))) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")))))
                           .Select(l => new
                           {
                               roleUri = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")).Value,
                               href = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")).Value
                           }).Distinct(l => l.roleUri).ToDictionary(a => a.roleUri);
```

**Update**

Or you can use grouping:

```
var roleRefList = xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleRef") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")))) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")))))
                           .Select(l => new
                           {
                               roleUri = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")).Value,
                               href = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")).Value
                           })
                           .GroupBy(l => l.roleUri)
                           .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: +1.  Would it be possible to use g.First rather than g.FirstOrDefault? I'd expect the group to always have at least one member.

Comment: Yes, you can use `First` as well

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate attributes are **not allowed** in XML. If you will have two `roleURI` attributes in `roleRef` element then you will get exception during XDocument loading:

> 'roleURI' is a duplicate attribute name. Line 42, position 42.

So, actually your code should look like this:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("foo.xml");
XNamespace ns = "http://www.adventure-works.com"; // put your namespace here

Dictionary<string, string> roleRefList = 
   xdoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "roleRef")
       .Select(r => new {
             Uri = (string)r.Attribute("roleURI"),
             Href = (string)r.Attribute("href")
       })
       .Where(r => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Uri) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Href))
       .ToDictionary(r => r.Uri, r => r.Href);
```

Result will be same as with your *for* loop. Sample xml:

```
<root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">
  <roleRef/>
  <roleRef roleURI=""/>
  <roleRef href=""/>
  <roleRef roleURI="" href=""/>
  <roleRef roleURI="a" />
  <roleRef roleURI="" href="b"/>
  <roleRef roleURI="c" href="d"/>
</root>
```

Comment: its giving me error when i an giving namespace value however it works with name.localname

Comment: @lokendrajayaswal if you don't have namespace, then leave at as is (or remove ns from code). If you have namespace defined (e.g. `<root xmlns="http://www.adventure-works.com">`) then create `XNamespace ns = "http://www.adventure-works.com";`. Take a look on xml namespaces in linq here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to achieve this:

**1)** You can call the distinct method using a custom equality comparer. In order to achieve this you will need to write a class which will contain the roleUri and href fields first. Something like:

```
    public class AttributePair 
    {
      public string RoleUri {get; set;}
      public string Href {get; set;}
    }
```

Next step is writing the equality comparer for your class:

```
    public class AttributePairComparer : IEqualityComparer<AttributePair>
    {
        public bool Equals(AttributePair x, AttributePair y)
        {
            return x.RoleUri.Equals(y.RoleUri);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(AttributePair obj)
        {
            return obj.RoleUri.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

And after that we'll just pass the instance of the equality comparer to the distinct method:

```
 var roleRefList = xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleRef") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")))) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")))))
                       .Select(l => new AttributePair
                       {
                           RoleUri = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")).Value,
                           Href = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")).Value
                       }).Distinct(new AttributePairComparer()).ToDictionary(a => a.RoleUri, a => a.Href);
```

I agree that this solution is quite complicated, but this is a classic way of achieving the needed result, so to speak.

**2)** Another solution is a [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) method from [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). Where you can pass a lambda expression as a parameter:

```
 var roleRefList = xDocument.Root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleRef") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")))) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")))))
                       .Select(l => new
                       {
                           roleUri = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("roleURI")).Value,
                           href = l.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name.LocalName.Equals("href")).Value
                       }).DistinctBy(p => p.roleUri).ToDictionary(a => a.roleUri, a => a.href);
```

**3)** The chief architect of C#, Anders Hejlsberg, suggested the solution which uses GroupBy. You can read about it [here.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6834054e-e1c1-49db-970c-370a9012c675)