# vb.net - "is in array" function?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

is there any easy way how to find if any string is present in array of strings without any looping through them?

Example:

```
Dim array1() As String = {"blue", "white", "black", "yellow", "red"}
Dim check as String = "blue"
Dim response as Boolean

response = check isinarray(array1) 'or something like this - in this case 'response' should be true
```

All I need is to get true/false (in case it is (or not) present), no index of it or anything else. It can be even case sensitive etc.
How to correctly declare this array and how to "ask" for a presence of a string in the values of the array please?

Comment: It is not clear if you want a comparison case-sensitive or not. Eventually this other question has the example required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952679/how-can-i-make-array-contains-case-insensitive-on-a-string-array

Comment: Use `.Contains`

Comment: Thank you everyone, ```.Contains``` is the solution!