# C# Linq Except By property values only on a dynamic List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to find the differences between two Lists of dynamic objects. The objects do not have the same reference and so I must override Linq Except, however while I could do this if I knew what the object type was in advance, I do not know how to do this when it is dynamic. I want to ensure all the properties of the object are the same. I know that both Lists will have the same object type when the comparison is run, but I don't know what object type that will be. Can this be done?

EDIT: This is the method as declared:

```
private List<ChangedData> MapNewListItem(IEnumerable<dynamic> oldData, IEnumerable<dynamic> newData)
```

For example:

```
List<MyObject> ListOne = new List<MyObject> { 
  new MyObject { Location: "France", Name: "Dave" }, 
  new MyObject { Location: "UK", Name: "Steve" }
};

List<MyObject> ListTwo = new List<MyObject> {
  new MyObject { Location: "France", Name: "Dave" }, 
  new MyObject { Location: "UK", Name: "Steve" }, 
  new MyObject { Location: "Germany", Name: "Alan" }
};


var result = ListTwo.Except(ListOne);
```

Here I would like `result` to be a `List<MyObject>` containing a `MyObject` with properties `Location: "Germany", Name: "Alan"`.

And here:

```
List<AnotherObject> ListOne = new List<AnotherObject> { 
  new AnotherObject{ Url: "http://google.com", Time: "4pm" }
};

List<AnotherObject> ListOne = new List<AnotherObject> { 
  new AnotherObject{ Url: "http://google.com", Time: "4pm" },
  new AnotherObject{ Url: "http://yahoo.com", Time: "5pm" },
};


var result = ListTwo.Except(ListOne);
```

I would like the result to be a `List<AnotherObject>` with a `AnotherObject` with properties `Url: "http://yahoo.com, Time: "5pm"`

But both of these scenarios must be handled by the exact same method.

Thank you.

Comment: And how is that method declared? What argument types would you like to give it? `List<T>`? `object`?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299513/ienumerable-except-and-a-custom-comparer create custom comparers

Comment: @JeroenMostert The method is: `private List<ChangedData> MapNewListItem(IEnumerable<dynamic> oldData, IEnumerable<dynamic> newData)`

Comment: See, that's why I asked, as that makes a great deal of difference for the implementation! If you don't want to implement equality separately on each type, this will effectively require reflecting over the properties of the arguments, meaning a dynamic `IEqualityComparer`. I can't help but think your choice of typing is not convenient at all here, and you should probably see if you can move to `Dictionary<string, string>` or perhaps `ValueTuple`s (i.e. `new List<(string url, string time)>`) so you can treat the data *as data*.

Comment: You can make a generic method for that, accepting a required type, if you know `AnotherObject` and `MyObject` exact types

Comment: Note that `ValueTuple`s are particularly attractive in this case because they come with built-in comparison implementations, so things like `Enumerable.Except` will do exactly what you'd expect them to do (for the most part, it can't do things like case-insensitive comparison out of the box, that still requires a custom comparer).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I can see now that a ValueTuple would definitely be a better way to do this and involve much less overhead. I will rework my code to use it instead. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide an `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>` to the [`.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) method. An [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.8) is meant to compare two instances of `T` for equality.

If you want one that makes sure every property of given objects are equal then you can implement it this way :

```
public class AllPropertiesEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private PropertyInfo[] publicInstanceProperties;

    public AllPropertiesEqualityComparer()
    {
        publicInstanceProperties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in publicInstanceProperties)
        {
            if (property.CanRead && property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0 && !property.GetValue(x).Equals(property.GetValue(y)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        long stackedHashCodes = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in publicInstanceProperties)
        {
            stackedHashCodes += property.GetValue(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
        return (int)(stackedHashCodes % int.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do this, because I do not know that the object will have the `Location` and `Name` properties. I need a method that can work with many different types of objects.

Comment: @Blocky Then what do you know to decide how to compare?

Comment: I want to ensure that all the properties of any object passed in are the same. Sorry if I am unclear.

Comment: @Blocky I edited my answer does it match your needs now?

Comment: This is perfect. Does exactly what I need. I am now aware of the overheads of doing this so will work towards refactoring my code, but I will mark this as accepted for this question. Thank you!

Comment: @Blocky You probably have to edit my code if you want it to work in case a property is `null`, I don't have time to do it right now but i'll edit my answer to fix this later if nobody did

Answer (score 0):

You can use Except() as is. All you have to do is override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` method of the `AnotherObject`-Class (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: For clarification: The default `Equals`-method compares references. You want to compare the properties of the class, so you have to override the `Equals`-method

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Except method on dynamic lists as well:

```
private List<dynamic> MapNewListItem(IEnumerable<dynamic> oldData, IEnumerable<dynamic> newData){   
  return oldData.Except(newData).ToList(); 
}
```

The Except method will use the 'equals' and 'GetHashCode' methods of your dynamic objects, so you should make sure they are implemented correctly.