# Is there a way in C# to use EXCEPT to compare 2 lists when one doesn't have Id yet?

Tags: c#, list, linq, except

I get listA from the database. I get listB from a file that the end user uploads, which I convert to the right class in a list. For the example I give you a list that came from the database and one that the user uploaded. You can find samples of these below.

I need to check if listB is in listA, but when I use `Except` I get the entire list because Id isn't in listB (auto numeration in database). I have a solution for now, but is there a better way to do this?

### What I have tried so far:

```
List<CustomerGroup> listC = listA.Except(listB).ToList(); 
    //Returns listA in listC because Id isn't the same
```

This is what I am using now, but it seems so redundant.

```
foreach (CustomerGroup itemToCheck in listB)
{
    var foundItem = listA.Find(dbItem => dbItem.FirstName== itemToCheck.FirstName &&
                                            dbItem.FamilyName== itemToCheck.FamilyName &&
                                            dbItem.Quantity == itemToCheck.Quantity &&
                                            dbItem.Discount == itemToCheck.Discount);
    if(foundItem != null)
    {
        listA.Remove(foundItem);
        listB.Remove(itemToCheck);
    }
}

foreach (CustomerGroup itemToCheck in listB)
{
    // other code to check here
}
```

```
List<CustomerGroup> listA = new List<CustomerGroup>(){
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 1, FirstName = "Anna", FamilyName = "Shrek", Quantity = 5, Discount = 10},
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 2, FirstName = "Elsa", FamilyName = "Fiona", Quantity = 5, Discount = 10},
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 3, FirstName = "Olaf", FamilyName = "Donkey", Quantity = 5, Discount = 10},
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 4, FirstName = "Sven", FamilyName = "Dragon", Quantity = 5, Discount = 5},
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 5, FirstName = "Kristoff", FamilyName = "Puss", Quantity = 5, Discount = 10},
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 6, FirstName = "Sven", FamilyName = "Dragon", Quantity = 10, Discount = 15},
   new CustomerGroup {Id = 7, FirstName = "Kristoff", FamilyName = "Puss", Quantity = 10, Discount = 30}
};
```

```
List<CustomerGroup> listB = new List<CustomerGroup>(){
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Anna", FamilyName = "Shrek", Quantity = 5, Discount = 10},
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Elsa", FamilyName = "Fiona", Quantity = 5, Discount = 8},
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Sven", FamilyName = "Dragon", Quantity = 5, Discount = 5},
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Kristoff", FamilyName = "Puss", Quantity = 5, Discount = 10},
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Sven", FamilyName = "Dragon", Quantity = 10, Discount = 15},
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Kristoff", FamilyName = "Puss", Quantity = 10, Discount = 30},
   new CustomerGroup { FirstName = "Hans", FamilyName = "Farquaad", Quantity = 20, Discount = 40}
};
```

```
public class CustomerGroup{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string FamilyName {get; set;}
    public int Quantity{get; set;}
    public int Discount {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IEnumerable.Except() and a custom comparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299513/ienumerable-except-and-a-custom-comparer)

Comment: @Liam I did got some stuff from there, but I got very confused with the lambda naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `IEqualityComparer<>` for class `CustomerGroup` and then use `Except()`,

like,

```
public class CompareCustomerGroup : IEqualityComparer<CustomerGroup>
{
    public bool Equals(CustomerGroup dbCustomer, CustomerGroup uploadedCustomer)
    {
        if(dbCustomer == null || uploadedCustomer == null)
            return false;
        else 
             return dbCustomer.FirstName == uploadCustomer.FirstName &&
             dbCustomer.FamilyName == uploadCustomer.FamilyName &&
             dbCustomer.Quantity == uploadCustomer.Quantity &&
             dbCustomer.Discount == uploadCustomer.Discount;
             
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CustomerGroup customGroup)
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(customGroup.FirstName, customGroup.FamilyName , customGroup.Quantity, customGroup.Discount);
    }
}
```

Now try `Except()`,

```
List<CustomerGroup> listC = listA.Except(listB, new CompareCustomerGroup()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own `IEqualityComparer`, that ignores the `ID` property:

```
class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomerGroup>
{
    public bool Equals(CustomerGroup x, CustomerGroup y)
    {
        if(x is null) return y is null;
        if(y is null) return false;
        return x.FirstName == y.FirstName && x.FamilyName == y.FamilyName && x.Quantity == y.Quantity && x.Discount == y.Discount;
    }
    
    public int GetHashCode(CustomerGroup codeh)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Pass this to `Except`:

```
List<CustomerGroup> listC = listA.Except(listB, new MyEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gogy9g

Comment: This is a very good answer! Why do you return 'y is null' instead of 'false'?

Comment: When x is null, the code checks if y is also null. If so, then both are null and thus equal. But when reading it again I just realized that this will fail if only y is null (NullReferenceException will be thrown one line later). I will update my answer.

Comment: Please also note that this might be slow because all instances will have the same hash code. If you have really huge lists, Prasad Telkikar's solution might be better.