# How to compare arrays?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am having a class Employee with properties Name and ID

I am having an array Employee[] A an another array Employee[] B.  How can I compare the two arrays and remove the the values not present in B from A?

Comment: offtop: Strange tag "c#-4.0". Maybe "c#4.0" ? :-\

Comment: @SeeSharp: That's the common tag for C# 4.0.

Comment: do you mean property instead of attribute?

Answer (score 7):

```
var intersection = A.Intersect(B).ToArray();
```

Note that this uses the default `IEqualityComparer<Employee>` which is just going to be a reference comparison unless you've overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. Alternatively, you could implement `IEqualityComparer<Employee>` and use the overload of `Intersect` that takes in instance of `IEqualityComparer<Employee>`.

Comment: I did it, for B i`m having {API.Employee[9]} and +for A API.Employess[1] and there is indeed one common array, howver, there is no intersection.

Comment: Did you implement an IEqualityComparer as Jason suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use System.Collections.Generic?

I would do something like:

```
var listA = new List<Employee>(A);
var listB = new List<Employee>(B); //not sure if arrays implement contains, may not need this line

A = listA.where(e => listB.Contains(e)).toArray();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find some inspiration from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx aka the `RemoveAll()` method. You'll need to put the arrays into Lists, but that shouldn't stump you...

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate Jason's suggestion (comparison based on IDs):

```
class IDEmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public bool Equals(Employee first, Employee second)
    {
      return (first.ID == second.ID);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Employee employee)
    {
       return employee.ID
    }
}
```

...

```
var intersection = A.Intersect(B, new IDEmployeeComparer ()).ToArray();
```

[Jon Skeet's misc library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188120/can-i-specify-my-explicit-type-comparator-inline) allows specifying the comparer inline without having to create a separate class

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee[]  c = (from d in a where !b.Contains<Employee>(d) select d).ToArray<Employee>();
```