# Remove duplicates from array of struct

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I can't figured out in remove duplicates entries from an Array of struct

I have this struct:

```
public struct stAppInfo
{
    public string sTitle;
    public string sRelativePath;
    public string sCmdLine;
    public bool bFindInstalled;
    public string sFindTitle;
    public string sFindVersion;
    public bool bChecked;
}
```

I have changed the stAppInfo struct to class [here](http://pastebin.com/w2ALaA6p) thanks to **Jon Skeet**

The code is like this: (short version)

```
stAppInfo[] appInfo = new stAppInfo[listView1.Items.Count];

int i = 0;
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    appInfo[i].sTitle = item.Text;
    appInfo[i].sRelativePath = item.SubItems[1].Text;
    appInfo[i].sCmdLine = item.SubItems[2].Text;
    appInfo[i].bFindInstalled = (item.SubItems[3].Text.Equals("Sí")) ? true : false;
    appInfo[i].sFindTitle = item.SubItems[4].Text;
    appInfo[i].sFindVersion = item.SubItems[5].Text;
    appInfo[i].bChecked = (item.SubItems[6].Text.Equals("Sí")) ? true : false;
    i++;
}
```

I need that **appInfo** array be unique in **sTitle** and **sRelativePath** members the others members can be duplicates

**EDIT:**

Thanks to all for the answers but this application is "portable" I mean I just need the .exe file and I don't want to add another files like references *.dll so please no external references this app is intended to use in a pendrive

All data comes form a *.ini file what I do is: (pseudocode)

```
ReadFile()
FillDataFromFileInAppInfoArray()
DeleteDuplicates()
FillListViewControl()
```

When I want to save that data into a file I have these options:

1. Using ListView data
2. Using appInfo array (this is more faster¿?)
3. Any other¿?

**EDIT2:**

Big thanks to: Jon Skeet, Michael Hays thanks for your time guys!!

Comment: You still have a mutable struct which ignores .NET naming conventions - and you should look into automatically implemented properties...

Comment: I rewrote my answer to match what you were asking for as closely as possible.  Please take a look and tell me what you think.  I agree with the other suggestions in this question, but realized I might have been hitting you with academia when you really just needed a solution.

Comment: @Jon .NET naming conventions, it's about coding rules??

Comment: @tttony: It's about making your code fit in with the rest of the code around you, so it's easy to read - and in particular so it's easy for other programmers to read.

Comment: @Jon OK for ex: sRelativePath to RelativePath??

Comment: @Michael I'm testing your implementation in fact this kind of code is very new for me, I'm basic developer I just code my own basics apps xDD

Comment: @tttony: Yes, and `stAppInfo` to something like `ApplicationInfo`. But getting rid of the horrible mutable struct would be my first priority...

Comment: @Jon I'm sorry but I don't get it when you say mutable what mean that??

Comment: @tttony: Did you try searching for it to find out? Search for "why are mutable structs evil" to find out a lot more...

Comment: @Jon yeah but I dont have the struct anymore, I changed to class like you recommend me

Comment: @tttony: It's still a struct in the update you posted... anyway, glad it's not any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a Set.  It ensures that the items entered into it are unique (based on some qualifier which you will set up).  Here is how it is done:

- First, change your struct to a class.  There is really no getting around that.
- Second, provide an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<stAppInfo>`.  It may be a hassle, but it is the thing that makes your set work (which we'll see in a moment):

  ```
  public class AppInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<stAppInfo>
  {
      public bool Equals(stAppInfo x, stAppInfo y) {
          if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
          if (x == null || y == null) return false;
          return Equals(x.sTitle, y.sTitle) && Equals(x.sRelativePath,
             y.sRelativePath);
      }

      // this part is a pain, but this one is already written 
      // specifically for your question.
      public int GetHashCode(stAppInfo obj) {
          unchecked {
              return ((obj.sTitle != null 
                  ? obj.sTitle.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397)
                  ^ (obj.sRelativePath != null 
                  ? obj.sRelativePath.GetHashCode() : 0);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Then, when it is time to make your set, do this:

  ```
  var appInfoSet = new HashSet<stAppInfo>(new AppInfoComparer());
  foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
  {
      var newItem = new stAppInfo { 
          sTitle = item.Text,
          sRelativePath = item.SubItems[1].Text,
          sCmdLine = item.SubItems[2].Text,
          bFindInstalled = (item.SubItems[3].Text.Equals("Sí")) ? true : false,
          sFindTitle = item.SubItems[4].Text,
          sFindVersion = item.SubItems[5].Text,
          bChecked = (item.SubItems[6].Text.Equals("Sí")) ? true : false};
      appInfoSet.Add(newItem);
  }
  ```
- `appInfoSet` now contains a collection of `stAppInfo` objects with unique Title/Path combinations, as per your requirement.  If you must have an array, do this:

  ```
  stAppInfo[] appInfo = appInfoSet.ToArray();
  ```

Note: I chose this implementation because it looks like the way you are already doing things.  It has an easy to read for-loop (though I do not need the counter variable).  It does not involve LINQ (wich can be troublesome if you aren't familiar with it).  It requires no external libraries outside of what .NET framework provides to you.  And finally, it provides an array just like you've asked.  As for reading the file in from an INI file, hopefully you see that the only thing that will change is your `foreach` loop.

**Update**

Hash codes can be a pain.  You might have been wondering why you need to compute them at all.  After all, couldn't you just compare the values of the title and relative path after each insert?  Well sure, of course you could, and that's exactly how another set, called `SortedSet` works.  `SortedSet` makes you implement `IComparer` in the same way that I implemented `IEqualityComparer` above.

So, in this case, `AppInfoComparer` would look like this:

```
private class AppInfoComparer : IComparer<stAppInfo>
{
   // return -1 if x < y, 1 if x > y, or 0 if they are equal
   public int Compare(stAppInfo x, stAppInfo y)
   {
      var comparison = x.sTitle.CompareTo(y.sTitle);
      if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
      return x.sRelativePath.CompareTo(y.sRelativePath);
   }
}
```

And then the only other change you need to make is to use SortedSet instead of HashSet:

```
var appInfoSet = new SortedSet<stAppInfo>(new AppInfoComparer());
```

It's so much easier in fact, that you are probably wondering what gives?  The reason that most people choose `HashSet` over `SortedSet` is performance.  But you should balance that with how much you actually care, since you'll be maintaining that code.  I personally use a tool called Resharper, which is available for Visual Studio, and it computes these hash functions for me, because I think computing them is a pain, too.

*(I'll talk about the complexity of the two approaches, but if you already know it, or are not interested, feel free to skip it.)*

`SortedSet` has a complexity of O(log n), that is to say, each time you enter a new item, will effectively go the halfway point of your set and compare.  If it doesn't find your entry, it will go to the halfway point between its last guess and the group to the left or right of that guess, quickly whittling down the places for your element to hide.  For a million entries, this takes about 20 attempts.  Not bad at all.  But, if you've chosen a good hashing function, then `HashSet` can do the same job, on average, in one comparison, which is O(1).  And before you think 20 is not *really* that big a deal compared to 1 (after all computers are pretty quick), remember that you had to insert those million items, so while `HashSet` took about a million attempts to build that set up, `SortedSet` took *several million* attempts.  But there is a price -- `HashSet` breaks down (very badly) if you choose a poor hashing function.  If the numbers for lots of items are unique, then they will collide in the `HashSet`, which will then have to try again and again.  If lots of items collide with the exact same number, then they will retrace each others steps, and you will be waiting a long time.  The millionth entry will take a million times a million attempts -- `HashSet` has devolved into O(n^2).  What's important with those big-O notations (which is what O(1), O(log n), and O(n^2) are, in fact) is how quickly the number in parentheses grows as you increase n.  Slow growth or no growth is best.  Quick growth is sometimes unavoidable.  For a dozen or even a hundred items, the difference may be negligible -- but if you can get in the habit of programming efficient functions as easily as alternatives, then it's worth conditioning yourself to do so as problems are cheapest to correct closest to the point where you created that problem.

Comment: Given your comments on mine and Albin's answers, I'd have expected your answer *not* to involve creating any more `stAppInfo` instances than required. This will require the same number to be constructed - it just doesn't require them all to be in memory at the same time. The items would still need to be constructed in order to be tested for existence in the set.

Comment: Looks like overkill for this particular case

Comment: For such particular cases when you need to compare items by single property it is not a good idea to implement IEqualityComparer, usign LabmdaCOmparer you can provide in place a comparision logic for each particular case

Comment: These items are coming from a list view. How often will that contain thousands of items? Resist the temptation to optimize prematurely :)

Comment: @silev.  Absolutely.  I definitely agree that a LambdaComparer is far more terse, and it takes writing an IEqualityComparer once or twice to decide that you really would like to have one.  But it's not part of the standard library yet.

Comment: @Jon it's hardly premature optimization when the LINQ form of the creation is easier to understand and faster to type than the two-stage creation.  Knowing this idiom for making arrays is a good idea as it works equally well in environments where one cares or does not care about performance.

Comment: @Michael: It looks like premature optimization to me - because it's easier to understand what the collection is distinct on when you've already provided names for those properties. Suppose the order of `SubItems` changes, but we still want to be unique on the same logical properties - you've got to remember to change two bits of code in your scheme, but only one in the original.

Comment: @Michael: Just imageine that entities with such implementation of GetHashC0de() would be inserted in the Dictionary/Map... a lot of hash collisions -> a lot of buckets -> slowness? And what about sorting  which uses Equals in .NET?

Comment: @silev  `Distinct` instantiates a set internally, so whether you provide `GetHashCode`, or you rely on the one generated for anonymous type, it is still going to happen.  But in your example, you are both making a new instance of stAppInfo when you don't have to *and* you are making a new instance of an anonymous class, which is also unnecessary.

Comment: @Jon if it is simply that I did not include `x => new { item.Text, item.SubItems[1].Text }` in my own LINQ code, it is because LambdaComparer is very simple and removes an unnecessary instance.  If you are suggesting that, in the middle of scraping the list control, the order of columns changes -- that would be an issue for either solution.  The HashSet implementation separates the visual logic of a list control from the business objects one should take away from that control.  At any rate -- your response will, utilizing a second pass through the collection, return only distinct elements.

Comment: @Michael: No, I'm saying that in my solution and Albin's, the "distinct by" makes it *clear* what the distinct columns are, and will not change regardless of the mapping. The mapping information (`item.SubItems[1]` corresponds to the relative path) is only expressed once, which I view as a useful property of my solution.

Comment: Sorry, @Jon. In both of my solutions, the mapping information of the list control is considered only once.  The difference in your solution and both of mine is that you require two passes, construct two arrays (and a set), and ultimately leave the `stAppInfo` array filled with duplicates.  When you finally do reassign your result to `stAppInfo`, I hope it is impressed upon you that you made three collections to solve a problem that could be solved in one, and could be solved with less code to boot, and doesn't require the programmer to install a third party library.

Comment: @Michael: You're expressing the mapping in both `myComparer` and then in the `stAppInfo` object initializer expression. It's hard to see that as you haven't provided full code, but I don't see how you'd prevent it. Now of course you don't *actually* have to construct the array to start with in order to use my approach - it could be done with a `Cast` followed by a `Select` from `listView.Items`, followed by the `DistinctBy` call. I was merely going with what the OP already had in order to concentrate on the problem at hand. I will edit my answer accrordingly. (Continued.)

Comment: At that point, if the OP doesn't want or need an array, the only concrete collection required would be the one within `DistinctBy`; the rest can be streamed. Additionally, that solution preserves the ordering which your approach of creating a `HashSet` doesn't. Oh, and the licence for MoreLINQ is quite amenable to this single useful method being included in your source code without the rest of the library. I note that you're happy to appeal to third party code in the form of `LambdaComparer` - why is `DistinctBy` different?

Comment: @Jon If an order preserving set is important, `SortedSet<T>` can be used.  Since you can initialize it directly from an `IEnumerable<T>` which comes directly off the LINQ into the list control, this is probably the most efficient production -- it's a shame then that we would then call ToArray() at the end.  Also, please note that my answer did not include a reference to LambdaComparer -- I submitted that the user should implement IEqualityComparer, and only afterwards suggested turning to a third party.  Please review the comments in my answer to see how that transpired.

Comment: @Michael: `SortedSet<T>` doesn't preserve the original order - it sorts according to the keys, which is very different. In fact, unless you either specify an `IComparer<T>` or make the elements comparable via `IComparable<T>` / `IComparable`, it will throw an exception.

Comment: @Jon - I stand corrected.  Regarding the SortedSet, you are correct.  If the original order is important, then the user can use my second solution, which preserves it just fine.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, he can use your solution (after adding a `Cast` call), which is slightly more efficient but requires specifying the mapping from a `ListViewItem` to the distinct columns separately from the projection from a `ListViewItem` to the final business object. I would be reluctant to sacrifice the clarity of my solution (which is subjective, certainly, but I think most would agree with my view on) for efficiency which you can't possibly know is required in the OP's situation.

Comment: @jon -- the difference is (now) simply a reordering of where to place the distinct operation.  I opt to do it earlier, you've opted to do it later.

Comment: @Michael: But that difference incurs a difference in how the logic for the distinct operation is expressed. I suggest you provide a full implementation (initializing `myComparer` and the `appInfo` values) and then compare how easy it is to work out at a glance what values are used for distinctness... and how natural it would be to change correctly if the subitems were reordered.

Comment: Could you post a link to the LambdaComparer implementation you're using? In particular, if it's this one: http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/b0255a8b-a5e5-4a7c-9f2a-f6a4c2f2c6f1.aspx then your solution now uses an equality comparer which always returns a hash of 0. That mean every single `HashSet` lookup or addition will be O(n) as it compares the new element with every single existing one. Personally I also find it *less* readable as it describes how to compare any two items for equality rather than the higher level idea of "this is the key I want to use for distinctness" too.

Comment: Of course you *could* use the overload of the `LambdaComparer` constructor which specifies a hash function, but then that's expressing how to get the elements of the key *yet again*. You could use my `ProjectionEqualityComparer` class to avoid this, but I'd rather just use `DistinctBy`...

Comment: (It's possible that you're using some *very* clever expression-tree-based implementation of LambdaComparer to generate an appropriate hash given an equality function, but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: Downvoted for the moment as you've turned an O(n) solution into an O(n^2) solution in the name of efficiency. You say that GetHashCode is "beyond the scope of your problem" but give sample code that you're recommending which will give awful performance.

Comment: @Jon I'd use `((A!=null ? A.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (B!=null ? B.GetHashCode():0)`. Why? I'm a fan of Resharper, and it generates Equality ops for me. Hey, maybe I'll use DistinctBy. But look, the issue with your first solution was that you initialized a collection and then filtered it in a second pass. Is that really so hard to swallow? You've incorporated my idea into your solution, and this is great. I do the same thing.  Don't let this become an ego thing -- I'll never get 700+ upvotes for submitting "h" as an answer, so you're good.  I'm providing the OP with alternatives.

Comment: @Michael: I didn't "incorporate your idea" - it's not like the idea of projecting while streaming is exactly a revelation to me. And yes, that looks like a reasonable hash code in this case - so include it in your solution, to stop it being an O(n^2) solution. My point is that you criticised mine (and Albin's) solution for a constant factor inefficiency, but then left an O(n^2) solution with no indication that it would perform awfully. The more I got you to clarify your solution, the more obvious it is how less readable it is than mine.

Comment: (Continued) You initially deemed picking a good hash code as "beyond the scope of your problem" - so you decided that creating a redundant collection is *inside* the scope, but giving the information that *unless you pick a reasonable hash code, using `IEqualityComparer<T>` will suck* was *outside* the scope? That seems a little odd to me.

Comment: @Jon: regarding LambdaComparer, yes I see it uses o => 0 by default. And about EqualityComparer<T>.Default - MSDN saying that it used IEqualityComparer<T> which is declared for T or Object.Equals() && Object.GetHashCode() provided by T, but it most likely that T does not provides such implementations so what hash function would be used in such case by EqualityComparer<T>.Default?

Comment: @Jon, sorry for disturbing, already found a description about default implementation

Comment: @sllev: I'm not sure what you mean about `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`  - where was that mentioned? Note that anonymous types override Equals and GetHashCode by delegating to the properties and combining the results.

Comment: @Jon: found it in your post as default comparer option (it was on 2008 year :) so perhaps out of date), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188120/can-i-specify-my-explicit-type-comparator-inline/188130#188130

Comment: @Michael let me understand this, when (var appInfoSet) is set then here enter AppInfoComparer() which call GetHashCode() then compare the member sTitle and sRelativePath

Comment: @ttony That's right.  When you add an element, it /could/ simply compare those two fields for equality -- this is how a SortedSet works.  But for a HashSet, one can get better performance by creating this artifical integer and using that first.  Since hash numbers can collide, it's possible two entries have the same hash, so in the end though, it will still have to actually compare the string values.  I'll update my answer to provide some more clarification.

Comment: @Michael thanks so much, I have tested both cases HashSet & SortedSet, for now I have the SortedSet version, the app is not the big thing to worry(for now) about the performance.. and I have to change the **private** to **public**

Comment: @ttony Hey alright!  Not a problem at all.  Good luck, and I'm glad I was able to help.  :-)

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, *please* don't use mutable structs. They're a bad idea in all kinds of ways.

Secondly, *please* don't use public fields. Fields should be an implementation detail - use properties.

Thirdly, it's not at all clear to me that this should be a struct. It looks rather large, and not particularly "a single value".

Fourthly, please follow the [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) so your code fits in with all the rest of the code written in .NET.

Fifthly, you can't *remove* items from an array, as arrays are created with a fixed size... but you can create a new array with only unique elements.

LINQ to Objects will let you do that already using [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) as shown by Albin, but a slightly neater (in my view) approach is to use [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) from [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com):

```
var unique = appInfo.DistinctBy(x => new { x.sTitle, x.sRelativePath })
                    .ToArray();
```

This is generally more efficient than `GroupBy`, and also more elegant in my view.

Personally I generally prefer using `List<T>` over arrays, but the above will create an array for you.

Note that with this code there can still be two items with the same title, and there can still be two items with the same relative path - there just can't be two items with the same relative path *and* title. If there are duplicate items, `DistinctBy` will always yield the *first* such item from the input sequence.

EDIT: Just to satisfy Michael, you don't actually need to create an array to start with, or create an array *afterwards* if you don't need it:

```
var query = listView1.Items
                     .Cast<ListViewItem>()
                     .Select(item => new stAppInfo
                             {
                                 sTitle = item.Text,
                                 sRelativePath = item.SubItems[1].Text,
                                 bFindInstalled = item.SubItems[3].Text == "Sí",
                                 sFindTitle = item.SubItems[4].Text,
                                 sFindVersion = item.SubItems[5].Text,
                                 bChecked = item.SubItems[6].Text == "Sí"
                             })
                     .DistinctBy(x => new { x.sTitle, x.sRelativePath });
```

That will give you an `IEnumerable<appInfo>` which is lazily streamed. Note that if you iterate over it more than once, however, it *will* iterate over `listView1.Items` the same number of times, performing the same uniqueness comparisons each time.

I prefer this approach over Michael's as it makes the "distinct by" columns very clear in semantic meaning, and removes the repetition of the code used to extract those columns from a `ListViewItem`. Yes, it involves building more objects, but I prefer clarity over efficiency until benchmarking has proved that the more efficient code is actually required.

Comment: This suffers the same issue as @Albin's response, as it insists that you pay for the complete construction of a superfluous `appInfo`.

Comment: @Michael: Unless there's any evidence that it's an issue, I would suggest that's still better than deduping based on `item.Text` and `item.SubItems[1].Text`, which is a lot less clear.

Comment: if this is the case, then I would suggest exposing only IEnumerable<IAppInfo> to implementations outside this class to communicate that this is not an array that should be modified once constructed.

Comment: @Michael: I think that's a separate issue. I would personally not use an array in the first place, but that's a very different issue. If I wanted to enforce it not changing, I'd probably wrap it in a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` - just exposing `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't prevent casting and mutation.

Comment: IEnumerable<T> does not prevent casting.  myCollection.Cast<MyNewType>.  Additionally -- returning `ToArray()` will prevent mutation.  However, I agree that a ReadOnlyCollection<T> is better form if indexed accessing is also important.

Comment: @Michael: `Cast<T>` doesn't always hide the original value - if you call `Cast<T>` on something which already implements `IEnumerable<T>`, it will just return the existing reference. It's not documented to do so from what I remember, but it does nonetheless. `ToArray` doesn't prevent mutation - it just prevents mutation of the original collection. A `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` will throw an exception if you try to mutate it, making it clearer that it's *really* not mutating anything.

Comment: @JonSkeet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2469/discussion-between-michael-hays-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: With your new update, you are almost there.  Add a call to `ToArray()` at the end so that the user does not have to run the query more than once, assign it to his original `stAppInfo` array, and you are home free.  At that point, it will be the same as my second solution.

Comment: @Michael: Why use `ToArray` when we don't *know* that he needs to do anything more than iterate over it more than once? I thought you hated creating collections pointlessly. That's why I explained the laziness after the code. Note that this *isn't* the same as your second solution, which has a comparer based on `ListViewItem` values rather than `appInfo` items. Oh, and your solution wouldn't compile because you're missing a call to `Cast` - `ListViewItemCollection` only implements `IEnumerable<T>`. My solution isn't "almost there" IMO - it's exactly where I want it to be.

Comment: Trust me, I do hate creating pointless collections.  My first solution provides guidance to use a Set instead of an array.  But since he is asking for a collection in his question, it stands to reason that we'll need to create at least one.  And you are right, your solution, which applies `Distinct` after the fact, is less efficient than running it before `Select`.  You are obviously the big dog here and will get the accepted answer, but I hope you can appreciate where I'm coming from.

Comment: @Michael: You are coming from a position of micro-optimizing without evidence, as far as I can see. I've acknowledged that my solution requires building more objects. You haven't yet acknowledged the duplication of logic in extracting business information from a `ListViewItem` in your solution yet though... it's not clear whether you even see what I mean. Do you?

Comment: I refer to the business mapping only once in my first solution, which I believe to be the superior solution.  In my second solution, I acquiesce to LINQ, and I recognize that `item.SubItems[1].Text` will appear twice, as will a reference to `item.Text`.  If this causes heartburn, then absolutely, `select(o => new { o, name=..., folder=... }).Select(t => new stAppInfo { sTitle = t.name ... });`.  My contention has been that you were filtering the objects, building your new object, after construction.

Comment: @Michael: That removes that particular duplication, but increases complexity. Oh, and if there are no duplicates, it'll have created a whole extra set of objects for no reason. Again, we have *no* indication that creating the duplicate objects in my solution has a significant performance penalty. I believe my code is the most *readable* approach which does what the OP wants, and would therefore recommend it until the performance characteristics suggest that optimization is required.

Comment: @Michael: Oh, and your preferred solution creates just as many instances of `stAppInfo` as mine does, as I pointed out before. I don't *think* you've addressed that point - care to do so now? In order to pass an `stAppInfo` value into any part of `HashSet<T>` (`Add`, `Contains` etc) you have to construct it first. Are you therefore willing to acknowledge that your preferred solution creates exactly the same number of `stAppInfo` values as mine? (Again, this would be clearer if you'd post the code for creating the `HashSet<T>` from the list view.)

Comment: My first solution does instantiate just as many `stAppInfo` instances as yours, it is true.  The savings is found in the construction and overhead of the collections.  I have provided sample code so that you can see that it is not as obtuse as you make it out to be.  The code you've provided after the edit is much better, and addresses the issues I had with it (two stage construction).  In fact, other than a semantic reordering (and yes, I find yours clearer), you've modified your answer to duplicate mine.

Comment: @Michael: I've modified my original answer to remove the original array construction and the final array construction, that's all. You make it sound like you provided all the ideas here, and I was just copying you. Oh, and I strongly suspect that your solution is now O(n^2)... I'll add a comment to your answer.

Comment: Yep, the original array construction and the final array construction was pretty much the entirety of my issue with your original solution.  Other than that, I'd have to be lip locked with you to give you more props than I already have on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ2Objects, group by the things that should be unique and then select the first item in each group.

```
var noDupes = appInfo.GroupBy(
    x => new { x.sTitle, x.sRelativePath })
    .Select(g => g.First()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as it requires him to incur the construction cost of his collection for items which should not even be in the collection, and which will continue to exist *with duplicates* after the construction is complete.

Answer (score 0):

**!!!** Array of structs (value type) + sorting or any kind of search ==> a lot of unboxing operations.

1. I would suggest to stick with recommendations of Jon and Henk, so make it as a class and use generic `List<T>`.
2. Use LINQ GroupBy or DistinctBy, as for me it is much simple to use built in GroupBy, but it also interesting to take a look at an other popular library, perhaps it gives you some insights.

BTW, Also take a look at the [LambdaComparer](http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/b0255a8b-a5e5-4a7c-9f2a-f6a4c2f2c6f1.aspx) it will make you life easier each time you need such kind of in place sorting/search, etc...

Comment: LambdaComparer will use 0 for the hash code for everything unless you specify it explicitly, leading to *awful* performance. I prefer my own `ProjectionEqualityComparer` in MiscUtil...

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I'll reuse it if you do not mind :) Found following link with comparer you've mentioned, does it up to date here is? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188120/can-i-specify-my-explicit-type-comparator-inline/188130#188130

Comment: Couldn't say without looking, but you may find other bits of MiscUtil useful too: http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil