# GroupBy on complex object (e.g. List<T>)

Tags: c#, linq, comparison, grouping

Using `GroupBy()` and `Count() > 1` I'm trying to find duplicate instances of my class in a list.

The class looks like this:

```
public class SampleObject
{
    public string Id;
    public IEnumerable<string> Events;
}
```

And this is how I instantiate and group the list:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<SampleObject>()
        {
            new SampleObject() { Id = "Id", Events = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" } },
            new SampleObject() { Id = "Id", Events = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" } }
        };

        var duplicates = items.GroupBy(x => new { Token = x.Id, x.Events })
                         .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                         .Select(g => g.Key)
                         .ToList();
    }
}
```

The `duplicates` contains no items. How can I make the grouping work?

Comment: By default Lists are not compared by values of their items.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - Which isn't the issue here. The problem is a lack of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` override.

Comment: @Enigmativity `new { Token = x.Id, x.Events }` has nothing to overriding Equals and GetHashCode of `SampleObject`. Issue here is completely caused by `x.Events` comparison

Comment: While I wouldn't use the `,` as a separator, the solution proposed by @Farhad (`string.Join`) is the classical one, and it is often "good enough". I would use a `'\0'` as a separator. Another "thing"... I would then use the `.Select(g => g.First())` to retrieve the duplicated items.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - Yes, fair enough. I had to resort to using a custom comparer with the original object.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get objects to work with many of LINQ's operators, such as `GroupBy` or `Distinct`, you must either implement `GetHashCode` & `Equals`, or you must provide a custom comparer.

In your case, with a property as a list you probably need a comparer, unless you made the list read only.

Try this comparer:

```
public class SampleObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<SampleObject>
{
    public bool Equals(SampleObject x, SampleObject y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Events.SequenceEqual(y.Events);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SampleObject x)
    {
        return x.Id.GetHashCode() ^ x.Events.Aggregate(0, (a, y) => a ^ y.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Now this code works:

```
    var items = new List<SampleObject>()
    {
        new SampleObject() { Id = "Id", Events = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent"} },
        new SampleObject() { Id = "Id", Events = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" } }
    };

    var comparer = new SampleObjectComparer();

    var duplicates = items.GroupBy(x => x, comparer)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .Select(g => g.Key)
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

`GroupBy()` will perform a default comparison, causing it to find your lists not equal.

See the following code:

```
var eventList1 = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" };
var eventList2 = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" };

Console.WriteLine(eventList1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(eventList2.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(eventList1.Equals(eventList2));
```

Two "equal" lists, right? However, this will print:

```
796641852
1064243573
False
```

So they're not considered equal, hence not grouped.

You need to provide a custom comparer, that will compare the relevant properties of the objects. Note that as shown before, `List<T>.GetHashCode()` does not properly represent the items *in* the list.

You can do that as such (from [Good GetHashCode() override for List of Foo objects respecting the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects-respecting-the-order) and [LINQ GroupBy on multiple ref-type fields; Custom EqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703186/linq-groupby-on-multiple-ref-type-fields-custom-equalitycomparer)):

```
public class SampleObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<SampleObject>
{
    public bool Equals(SampleObject a, SampleObject b)
    {
        return a.Id == b.Id 
            && a.Events.SequenceEqual(b.Events);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SampleObject a)
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + a.Id.GetHashCode();

        foreach (var evt in a.Events)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + evt.GetHashCode();
        }           

        return hash;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var eventList1 = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" };
var eventList2 = new List<string>() { "ExampleEvent" };

var items = new List<SampleObject>()
{
    new SampleObject() { Id = "Id", Events = eventList1 },
    new SampleObject() { Id = "Id", Events = eventList2 }
};

var duplicates = items.GroupBy(x => x, new SampleObjectComparer())
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(g => g.Key)
                 .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(duplicates.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>` has no overridden `Equals` + `GetHashCode`, that's why your `GroupBy` doesn't work as expected. One of the two properties of the anonymous type refer to the list, when the `GroupBy` has to compare two lists `Object.RefernceEquals` is used which only checks if both are the same reference and not if both contain the sample elements.

You could provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
public class IdEventComparer : IEqualityComparer<SampleObject>
{
    public bool Equals(SampleObject x, SampleObject y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) 
            return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) 
            return false;
        if(x.Id != y.Id) 
            return false;
        if (x.Events == null && y.Events == null)
            return true;
        if (x.Events == null || y.Events == null)
            return false;

        return x.Events.SequenceEqual(y.Events);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SampleObject obj)
    {
        if(obj == null) return 23;
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 23;
            hash = (hash * 31) + obj.Id == null ? 31 : obj.Id.GetHashCode();

            if (obj.Events == null) return hash;
            foreach (string item in obj.Events)
            {
                hash = (hash * 31) + (item == null ? 0 : item.GetHashCode());
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in many LINQ methods like also `GroupBy`:

```
var duplicates = items.GroupBy(x => x, new IdEventComparer())
     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
     .Select(g => g.Key)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Tim. Very nice example and explanation. However, when I try to implement this, using this line: var groupedOrderList = orders.OrderListD.GroupBy(u => u.Services[0].FeatureList, new FeatureAttributeComparer()).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList(); I get an error marked under the GroupBy clause which reads: The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. Have any idea what this error is?