# Returning Specific field in Linq .net core

Tags: c#, json, list, model-view-controller, .net-core

I am having a problem on returning the fields that I want. I have a model and I want to return a specific data from my Model.

Here is my model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace api.Models
{
    [Table("ScheduleSectionRows")]
    public partial class ScheduleSectionRows
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("ScheduleRowID")]
        public int ScheduleRowId { get; set; }
        [Column("RowID")]
        public int? RowId { get; set; }
        [Column("StadiumID")]
        public int? StadiumId { get; set; }
        [Column("SectionID")]
        public int? SectionId { get; set; }
        [Column("ScheduleID")]
        public int? ScheduleId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(20, 4)")]
        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public int? AvailableSeats { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string RowNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Basically I just want to return a Json object that returns the header of ScheduleID and the List of sectionsID of that ScheduleID.

Here's the return the sample data from the DB

```
[
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20491,
        "RowId": 4559,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 8,
        "RowNumber": "7"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20492,
        "RowId": 4560,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "8"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20493,
        "RowId": 4561,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "9"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20494,
        "RowId": 4562,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "10"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20495,
        "RowId": 4563,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "11"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20496,
        "RowId": 4564,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "12"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20497,
        "RowId": 4565,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 5,
        "RowNumber": "13"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20498,
        "RowId": 4566,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "14"
    },
    {
        "ScheduleRowId": 20499,
        "RowId": 4567,
        "StadiumId": 3,
        "SectionId": 81,
        "ScheduleId": 43,
        "Amount": 100,
        "AvailableSeats": 10,
        "RowNumber": "15"
    }
]
```

Basically here is the sample output that I want to get.

```
{
    "Status" : "Success",
    "ScheduleID" : 43,
    "SectionID": [
        {
            "SectionID" : 81,
        },
        {
            "SectionID" : 82,
        },
        {
            "SectionID" : 83,
        },
        {
            "SectionID" : 84,
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code that I have.

```
public async Task<SectionDTO<ScheduleSectionRows>> GetSection(int scheduleId)
{
    var data = _context.MlfbScheduleSectionRows
        .Where(s => s.ScheduleId == scheduleId)
        .GroupBy(
            s => s.SectionId,
            ( Section) => new { Section = Section})
        .ToListAsync();
    return new SectionDTO<MlfbScheduleSectionRows>("Success",scheduleId,data);
 }
```

Here is the DTO.

```
public class SectionDTO<T> where T : class
{
    public SectionDTO(string _status,int _scheduleID, IList<T> _data)
    {
        Status = _status;
        ScheduleID = _scheduleID;
        Data = _data;
    }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Can you explain what your current code is doing, and how the desired behaviour differs? Thanks

Comment: If you only want to return the `SessionID` field add a `Select` before `ToListAsync`, that returns only that, not the entire row. If you only want a list of SectionIDs though, you don't really need a `GroupBy`, a `Distinct` would also work. Eg: `.Where(s => s.ScheduleId == scheduleId).Select(s=>s.SessionID).Distinct()`

Comment: basically the code is not working, what I am trying to do is to create a List of sectionID and put it to the data variable. and return it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for that query, I had an error in my data variable it says "cannot convert from System.Threading.Task.Task<System.Collection.Generic.List<API.Models.ScheduleSectionRows>> to 'Systems.Colelctions.Generic.IList<API.Models.ScheduleSectionRows>'"

Comment: @Novice what did you write? Sounds like you put `.Select()` *after* the call to `ToListAsync()` instead of *before*

Comment: .Where(s => s.ScheduleId == scheduleId).Select(s=> s.SectionId).Distinct().ToListAsync() here's what I wrote.

Comment: @Novice did you forget to `await` the task? `ToListAsync()` returns a `Task<List<T>>`, not the actual results.

Comment: Nope sir. I wrote the await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the results looks like all that's needed is to return distinct SectionIDs. It could be rewritten as :

```
var query = _context.MlfbScheduleSectionRows
    .Where(s => s.ScheduleId == scheduleId)        
    .Select(s => s.SectionId)
    .Distinct();
var data = await query.ToListAsync();
```

`ToListAsync()` doesn't return the data itself, it returns a Task that will return the data once it completes. `await` is needed to await that task and get the data.

The SQL query will look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SectionID
FROM ScheduleSectionRows
WHERE ScheduleId = @p0
```

The result is a `List<int?>` which would be serialized to JSON as:

```
[ 11, 23, 43 ]
```

To get the desired result we'd have to convert return a type that contains only a single `SectionID` property. LINQ's `.Select()` could easily return an anonymous type, eg `data.Select(id=>new {SectionId = id})` but we need an actual "named" type to pass to `SectionDTO`.

```
public class Section
{
    public int? SectionID {get;set;}
}

....

public async Task<SectionDTO<Section>> GetSection(int scheduleId)
{
    var query = _context.MlfbScheduleSectionRows
                        .Where(s => s.ScheduleId == scheduleId)        
                        .Select(s => s.SectionId)
                        .Distinct();
    var data = await query.ToListAsync();
    var sections=data.Select(id=>new Section{SectionID=id})
                     .ToList();

    return new SectionDTO<Section>("Success",scheduleId,sections);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Sir, is there something wrong in my SectionDTO? specially in the IList<T> Data field? Coz Im getting the same error.

Comment: What error is that? If it's about `Task<System.Collection.Generic.List<API.Models.ScheduleSectionRows>>`, you have to use `await` with the taks returned by `ToListAsync()`

Comment: here's the error sir "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MLFBapi.Models.Section>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MLFBapi.Models.Section>'"

Comment: @Novice I added a `.ToList()` after `data.Select()`. LINQ queries return `IEnumerable<>` results. Your `SectionDTO` expects an `IList<>` which is implemented by lists and arrays

Comment: Wow! Thank you sir. How can I commend you?

Answer (score -1):

You have to create c# model according to your json response something like this

```
public class SectionID
{
    public int SectionID { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
    public List<SectionID> SectionID { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can fill up this model using `Linq .select`.

Comment: how can I fill it up?

Comment: You made variable named "data" which is List. so you can do like this  :  data.select(x => new RootObject { "assign your properties here" });

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The problem is how to write the `Select` statement. The `root` object already exists, it's SectionDTO.

Comment: where "x" will be list item.

Answer (score -1):

When using `groupby` with reference type, please ensure that you override `equals` and `gethashcode` methods. These are used for generating the "key" of your grouped entity.

In the code below, I have removed the constraint `where T : class` on your `SectionDTO` and using the key to be int (non-reference type). It is grouping up the values.

```
                //using Newtonsfot.Json library

                //using it to get the list data below, not required for the solution
                JArray j = JArray.Parse(GetJSONString());

                //Select the schedule id/section id as a list
                var list = j.Select(x => new { ScheduleId= Convert.ToInt32(x["ScheduleId"]) ,SectionID = Convert.ToInt32(x["SectionId"]) });

                //group by into a SectionDTO object 
                var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.ScheduleId, (key, value) => new SectionDTO<int> { Status = "Success", ScheduleID = key,  Data = value.Select(x=>x.SectionID).ToList() });

                //if you want to convert it to a json string then use the convert method
                string JSonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: There's no need to override anything, even for LINQ to objects. In this case it's LINQ to EF and the query will be translated to a `GROUP BY` clause in a SQL query. Manual JSON generation isn't required either. JSON.NET can serialize any object, even anonymous types, just fine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos JSON use: I never said it is requred, I just used it as it was easier for me to parse the string provided to create the data list. I will edit my code to reflect the same. Override: For Linq to object we need to provide the equality methods (override them) since the runtime will use them for comparing keys. LINQ to EF I am not aware of.

Comment: Forgot to paste the link earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128996/groupby-on-complex-object-e-g-listt

Comment: There's no string to parse. Those are database results. This isn't about LINQ to Objects. No, we don't need to override those methods with LINQ - different queries have *different* critera for equality or comparison. That's why the relevant LINQ methods accept key selector and comparer parameters. Equals and GetHashCode are used for general-purpose equality comparisons

Comment: The sample data that the user has provided above. I am using it to generate the object needed to work on the code, instead of setting up the entire entity structure. Just think of it as my mocking of the data. In actual case user would get the list `var list` from his DB.