# C# Add Unique Items Together in a Custom Object

Tags: c#, .net

I created a custom object that I'm populating with some data.  How can I list the total of the same. For example:

```
dog,dog,dog,cat
dog,dog,dog,cat
dog,dog,dog,dog
```

I need it to count and produce:

```
1 each - dog,dog,dog,dog
2 each - dog,dog,dog,cat
```

---

I try below code:

```
     var info = new List<SData>();
                    var sinfo = new List<SData>();

                    if (plist.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (P p in plist)
                        {
                            pinfo.Add(new SData
                            {
                                n = p.N,
                                s = p.S,
                                l = p.L,
                                m = p.P
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: So what you are asking is how to count occurrences of objects with similar data and then display this?

Comment: what's n,s,l,and m ?

Comment: hi @SimonJensen , that is what i'm trying to do

Comment: hi @auburg they are strings. thank you

Comment: found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128996/groupby-on-complex-object-e-g-listt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GroupBy on complex object (e.g. List<T>)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128996/groupby-on-complex-object-e-g-listt)