# Delete Duplicated Node From XML

Tags: xml, .net-core

I have a complex XML that represents an invoice.

I need to generate an XML structure like the following using .NET Core and `XmlSerializer`:

```
<DetalleServicio>
  <LineaDetalle>
    ALL MY VALUES HERE
  </LineaDetalle>
  <LineaDetalle>
    MY VALUES HERE
  </LineaDetalle>
</DetalleServicio>
```

As you can see, `DetalleServicio` can contain a lot of `LineaDetalle` childs.

I'm trying to make this work using some classes, so I have:

```
public class DetalleServicio
{
  public List<LineaDetalle> LineaDetalle { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class LineaDetalle
{
   public int NumeroLinea { get; set; }
   public CodigoProducto[] Codigo { get; set; }
   public decimal Cantidad { get; set; }
   public string UnidadMedida { get; set; }
   public string UnidadMedidaComercial { get; set; }
   public string Detalle { get; set; }
   public decimal PrecioUnitario { get; set; }
   public decimal MontoTotal { get; set; }
   public decimal MontoDescuento { get; set; }
   public string NaturalezaDescuento { get; set; }
   public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
   public Impuesto Impuesto { get; set; }
   public decimal MontoTotalLinea { get; set; }
}

Finally I'm doing something like this

DetalleServicio = new DetalleServicio()
{
  LineaDetalle = new List<LineaDetalle>()
  {
    new LineaDetalle()
    {
    },
    new LineaDetalle()
    {
    }
   }
 }
```

Finally we generate our XML using `XmlSerializer`, but the problem is that `XmlSerializer` writes `LineaDetalle` as parent and `LineaDetalle` as childs, for example:

```
<DetalleServicio>
  <LineaDetalle>
    <LineaDetalle>
      ALL MY VALUES HERE
    </LineaDetalle>
    <LineaDetalle>
      MY VALUES HERE
    </LineaDetalle>
  </LineaDetalle>
</DetalleServicio>
```

How can I solve this problem? I tried using `XmlDocument` to delete parent `<LineaDetalle>` node but it throws a "cs0..." error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [efficiently removing duplicate xml elements in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812456/efficiently-removing-duplicate-xml-elements-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer:

Because i'm using

```
public List<LineaDetalle> LineaDetalle { get; set; }
```

and

```
LineaDetalle = new List<LineaDetalle>()
 {
    new LineaDetalle()
    {}
    new LineaDetalle()
    {}
}
```

When using xmlserialize it causes to have two levels of hierarchy to represent the `List<LineaDetalle>` collection. You have the `<LineaDetalle>` tag and then you have a `<LineaDetalle>` tag for every Detail in the collection

So, to eliminate the tag with XmlSerializer, simply update the LineaDetalle member with an XmlElementAttribute that specifies the name you want to use for each item

For example

```
 [XmlElement("LineaDetalle")]
 public List<LineaDetalle> LineaDetalle { get; set; }
```

Now the instance is being serializer without the extra  tag