# Speed Up Performance - LINQ to get items in one LIST, that are not in another List

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists and I'm trying to return items that are not in the other list. Here is my code:

```
var Results = ListOne.Where(x => ListTwo.All(a => a.EmployeeNum != x.EmployeeNum && a.Sched != x.Sched));
```

This takes about 9-10 seconds to complete. ListOne has about 1200 records and ListTwo has about 33000 records.

Comment: That's going to be difficult to speed up using lists. One approach could be to turn `ListTwo` into a `HashSet<T>`, then you could just use the set's `Contains` method.

Comment: I won't be able to change it into a set because there are duplicate employee numbers, but they have different sched. I believe a Set needs to be unique for every element.

Comment: @Kane: `HashSet<Tuple<TypeOfEmployeeNum, TypeOfShed>>` with a help of `Tuple` you combine two properties into one

Comment: Use the Except method with a custom equality comparer, i.e. `var results = ListOne.Except(ListTwo, ProjectionEqualityComparer<YourListItemClass>.Create(x => (x.EmployeeNum, x.Sched));` using Jon Skeet's [ProjectionEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188120/can-i-specify-my-explicit-type-comparator-inline).

Comment: MoreLinq's `ExceptBy` - https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/

Comment: I suspect if we knew where the two lists came from (Queries) there would be better ways to do this too, with instantiating two lists to then compare.

Answer (score 4):

Using `HashSet<T>`, as it has `O(1)` search time could improve performances, e.g.

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<T>(ListTwo.Select(x => Tuple.Create(x.EmployeeNum, x.Sched)));
var results = ListOne.Where(x => !hashSet.Contains(Tuple.Create(x.EmployeeNum, x.Sched)));
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but for someone reason the HashSet is coming back with more than what was in the list. Shouldn't it be the equal amount of items?

Comment: @Kane shouldn't be more but less(if you have duplicates) or equal

Comment: sorry. I misread the numbers. So if there's duplicate in EmployeeNum, it will omit that? Even though EmployeeNum can have different/multiple Sched that was originally in the List.

Comment: @Kane duplicates are entries with the same `EmployeeNum` and `Sched`...

Answer (score 2):

You can also create your own IEqualityComparer (assumes you have a class called `Employee`):

```
var results = ListTwo.Except(ListOne, new EmployeeComparer());
```

IEqualityComparer Implementation:

```
public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>
{
    public int GetHashCode(Employee co)
    {
        if (co == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return co.EmployeeNum.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Employee x1, Employee x2)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x1, x2))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x1, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(x2, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x1.EmployeeNum == x2.EmployeeNum && x1.Sched == x2.Sched;
    }
}
```

Comment: ['Except'](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs.html#64071682ee3bf309) uses a hashset internally, so your implementation will perform poorly in case there are multiple items with the same EmployeeNum and different Sched. You should create a combined hashcode of these two properties. `EqualityComparer` classes ought to have consistent implementations of `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias do you have any sources/reading material? I would like to learn more about this.

Comment: Sure. Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) that we derive from the EqualityComparer<T> class instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer<T> interface. Some [guidelines for GetHashCode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/). About combining hashcodes: [Quick and Simple Hash Code Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646807/quick-and-simple-hash-code-combinations)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var Results = ListOne.AsParallel().Where(x => ListTwo.All(a => a.EmployeeNum != x.EmployeeNum && a.Sched != x.Sched)).ToList();
```

Comment: Some notes explaining why `AsParallel` might be helpful would be beneficial.